# Load HTML templates using YUI 3 Loader Utility

Tags: templates, yui, requirejs, loader, yui3

ReqireJS allows [text file dependency](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text), is there similar way to do this in YUI3 loader utility. I have been trying to do this with YUI.io module. but I would prefer if I can extend YUI3 Loader module in anyway to satisfy the need.

Comment: Loader doesn't support this out of the box. Sounds like something you can file a feature request for. http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/newticket/